# Is "smothersome" a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

A variation of "smother", obviously, to describe someone with an inclination to smother other people.

"You're just too needy and smothersome."

Thoughts? Corrections? Suggestions?

Edit: Apologies and clarification. I did find a Google search result that states that this word is an adjective which describes something that is easily smothered. But to me, this word sounds akin to "bothersome": causing bother, troublesome. To me, "smothersome" wouldn't describe something that is easily smothered, instead it would describe something that does the smothering...

Comment: I think you are looking for ***smotherer***: a person or thing that smothers. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smotherer

Comment: The ***-some*** suffix is commonplace in many words *(troublesome, awesome, lonesome, cumbersome)*, but ***smothersome*** is a [fairly unusual](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22smothersome%22) (though not inherently "incorrect") form. You might be safer sticking to the more idiomatic ***smothering*** for your context. You're right that *bothersome* = that which (or *one who*) bothers (others); *smothersome* = that which smothers). The addressee in your cite is figuratively *hot and humid; suffocating* (smothering the speaker).

Comment: It's a word if you want it to be a word.

Comment: These are all good thoughts. Thank you for your input. Max - You're absolutely right; Shakespeare did it, so I guess why can't I as well?